# Erroneous fomula in `rugarch` package documentation

Tags: r, time-series, garch, finance

I think there is a mistake in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) of the `rugarch` package. In page 9, where it gives the equation of the fGARCH (family GARCH), it includes a $\sigma_{t-j}$ together with $\alpha$. I think this $\sigma$ should be omitted, since it does not even give you the standard GARCH that way, not to mention the other specifications.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You should ask the package author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the documentation is correct.

If you look at Hentschel ["All in the family Nesting symmetric and asymmetric GARCH models"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0304405X9400821H?via%3Dihub) (1995), namely its [open version](http://www.ludgerhentschel.com/PDFs/AIF.pdf) section 2.1.1 and 2.1.2, equations 1, 2 and 3, you will see that $\epsilon_t$ stands for standardized innovation, while $\eta_t=\sigma_{t-1}\epsilon_t$ stands for unstandardized innovation. It is typical to have $\alpha_i\eta^2_{t-i}$ in the conditional variance equation, but Hentschel uses $\alpha_i\sigma^2_{t-i}\epsilon^2_{t+1-i}$ (note the shifted time index for $\sigma$!) instead. While it is unusual, it is not incorrect. (The shift of the time index for $\sigma$ in equation 2 does not make it easier.)

Comment: Thank you very much prof. Hardy, I've been reading your answers here and there in time-series questions and they are life-savers!

Comment: However, in the rugarch documentation, \sigma_{t-j} should be replace by \sigma_{t-1-j} since it is then multiplied by z_{t-j}, the equivalent \epsilon using Hentschel's notation.

Comment: @GeorgiosStrat, Thank you. I am not sure the time index should be changed as you suggest, because in `rugarch` documentation, the equivalent of $\eta_t=\sigma_{t}\epsilon_t$ is used, unlike $\eta_t=\sigma_{t-1}\epsilon_t$ in Hentschel's paper.

Comment: I dont know how that would still be an av-garch if they work with $\eta_t=\sigma_t \epsilon_t$, but ok. Thanks

Comment: @GeorgiosStrat, this is just notation. A simpler example (perhaps too obvious) would be to say that $\eta_t=\sigma_{t-1}\epsilon_t$ and $\eta_{t+1}=\sigma_{t}\epsilon_{t+1}$ mean the same thing, though the time is shifted by 1. In the documentation, the case is not as obvious, but the essence is the same.